# will a pressure signal show if i have excess oil in my crankcase?

Tags: oil

you did not understand my Question. the reason i am asking is my an oil pressure signal keep coming up ,after a mechanic pure an excessive amount of oil in my car

Comment: How did we not understand your question? You have only just posted it and are moaning at us...

Comment: Pressure gauge - no. Checking the dipstick? Yes.

Comment: If the oil pressure light is still showing after you've filled the oil, then you have a problem either with your oil pump, oil filter, or oil pressure sensor.

Answer (score 1):

The oil pressure warning light comes "on" when there is insufficient oil pressure and the engine will suffer damage.

That warning light is not designed to check the oil level in the engine.

Some cars did have an oil level sensor fitted with a gauge similar to a fuel gauge, others made use of the oil pressure gauge to show the level before the engine ws started.